# Query error on a recordset.update vba line

Tags: vba, ms-access-2016

I am trying to print multiple labels for multiple records. The number of labels is consistent for any one run of the label report and all labels for the same record need to be together on the printed sheet. Parameters are entered on TakeNoticeForm and once a button is clicked a recordset, rsQuery, is created with TakeNoticeLabelQuery. Another recordset is created, rsTable, based on a table, TemporaryTNLabels. This table is a copy of my main table, Certificates, without data. I'm using nested For loops to parse through the query results and add "x" copies of said record into the temp table, which will then be used to print the labels. Once the labels are printed the data will be cleared from the temp table for use again later.

Everything I have so far appears to work until I actually start adding data to my temp table. I get Error 3991 - "The query failed to execute because the identifier '[Certificates].[TownshipID]' could not be found" and it points to .Update. [TownshipID] is a lookup field in the Certificates table that was the original for TemporaryTNLabels. I tried to keep the copy intact for possible reuse with other reports but I don't *need* that field for this report so deleted the lookup field from the temp table to hopefully solve the problem. TakeNoticeLabelQuery is actually a copy of another query, TakeNoticeQuery, that did reference Township information. Again, I was hoping to reuse objects but made a copy and only kept what I needed, which has no reference to TownshipID.

After stripping everything unnecessary away, I can't figure out why it's still trying to find [TownshipID]. I'm still trying to wrap my head around recordsets so wondering if the problem is actually elsewhere, buty I'm confused as to how this error is even remotely related to my code. Any help is appreciated. The SQL for the query and code for generating label data are below.

```
SELECT Certificates.DatabaseID, Certificates.CertCounty, Certificates.TaxYear, Certificates.ParcelNumber, Certificates.MailToFirstName, Certificates.MailToLastName, Certificates.MailToAlso, Certificates.MailToCity, Certificates.MailToState, Certificates.MailToZip
FROM Counties INNER JOIN Certificates ON Counties.ID = Certificates.CertCounty
WHERE (((Certificates.DatabaseID) Between ([Forms]![TakeNoticeForm]![FirstDBTextbox]) And ([Forms]![TakeNoticeForm]![LastDBTextbox])) AND ((Certificates.CertCounty) Like [Forms]![TakeNoticeForm]![CountyCombobox] & '*') AND ((Certificates.TaxYear) Like [Forms]![TakeNoticeForm]![TaxYearTextbox] & '*')) OR (((Certificates.CertCounty) Like [Forms]![TakeNoticeForm]![CountyCombobox] & '*') AND ((Certificates.TaxYear) Like [Forms]![TakeNoticeForm]![TaxYearTextbox] & '*') AND ((IsNull([Forms]![TakeNoticeForm]![FirstDBTextbox]))<>False) AND ((IsNull([Forms]![TakeNoticeForm]![LastDBTextbox]))<>False));

Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub TNLabelPreviewButton_Click()
    Dim iTab As Integer
    Dim iLabel As Integer
    Dim numLabels As Integer
    Dim totalRecords As Long
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim rsTable As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rsQuery As DAO.Recordset

    ' Set query definition for creating recordset
    Set db = CurrentDb()
    Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("TakeNoticeLabelQuery")
    If CurrentProject.AllForms("TakeNoticeForm").IsLoaded Then
        qdf.Parameters("[Forms]![TakeNoticeForm]![FirstDBTextbox]") = [Forms]![TakeNoticeForm]![FirstDBTextbox]
        qdf.Parameters("[Forms]![TakeNoticeForm]![LastDBTextbox]") = [Forms]![TakeNoticeForm]![LastDBTextbox]
        qdf.Parameters("[Forms]![TakeNoticeForm]![CountyCombobox]") = [Forms]![TakeNoticeForm]![CountyCombobox]
        qdf.Parameters("[Forms]![TakeNoticeForm]![TaxYearTextbox]") = [Forms]![TakeNoticeForm]![TaxYearTextbox]
'        qdf.Parameters("[Forms]![TakeNoticeForm]![TakeNoticeDateTextbox]") = [Forms]![TakeNoticeForm]![TakeNoticeDateTextbox]
    Else
        qdf.Parameters("[Forms]![TakeNoticeForm]![FirstDBTextbox]") = ""
        qdf.Parameters("[Forms]![TakeNoticeForm]![LastDBTextbox]") = ""
        qdf.Parameters("[Forms]![TakeNoticeForm]![CountyCombobox]") = ""
        qdf.Parameters("[Forms]![TakeNoticeForm]![TaxYearTextbox]") = ""
'        qdf.Parameters("[Forms]![TakeNoticeForm]![TakeNoticeDateTextbox]") = CStr(Date)
    End If
    Set rsQuery = qdf.OpenRecordset
    rsQuery.MoveLast
    totalRecords = rsQuery.RecordCount

    'Close and delete records from TemporaryTNLabels table.
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.Close acTable, "TemporaryTNLabels"
    DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE FROM [TemporaryTNLabels]"
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True

    numLabels = Me.NumLabelsTextbox
    MsgBox numLabels & " labels"

    'Open a table-type Recordset
    Set rsTable = db.OpenRecordset("TemporaryTNLabels", dbOpenTable)

    rsQuery.MoveFirst
    With rsTable
        For iTab = 1 To totalRecords
            For iLabel = 1 To numLabels
                Debug.Print rsQuery!DatabaseID
                .AddNew
                !ParcelNumber = rsQuery!ParcelNumber
                .Update                 ' <-------------------------This is where the error points.
                .Bookmark = .LastModified
            Next iLabel
            rsQuery.MoveNext
        Next iTab
    End With

'    DoCmd.OpenReport ReportName:="TakeNoticeLabelReport", View:=acViewPreview

    rsTable.Close
    Set rsQuery = Nothing
    Set qdf = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is why I stopped using lookup fields :-(

I would delete the table `TemporaryTNLabels` or rename it to `TemporaryTNLabels_OLD`. Then recreate the table `TemporaryTNLabels` from scratch with only one field `ParcelNumber`, and start from there.